# How do you pass an OutputStream as an InputStream in C#?

Tags: c#, io, stream

My goal is to read from one stream, transform that stream, and use it as an input to a library that accepts a `Stream` to read.

I am using two different libraries. One takes an output `Stream` and transforms it. Let's call it `TransformingOutputStream`. Its intended use is:

```
var outputStream = new TransformingOutputStream(finalDestinationOutputStream);
inputStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
```

I'm using another library that accepts an input `Stream`. It does whatever it needs and then reads from that stream. Its intended use is:

```
MagicStreamReadingLibrary.ProcessStream(someInputStream);
```

I can't pass `TransformingOutputStream` to it because its intended use is to be *written-to*, not read-from. I do not have control over either library.

**How do I hook-up the `TransformingOutputStream` to the library function that requires *reading* from an input `Stream`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far this is the best working example I have, using Anonymous Pipes:

```
using( var pipeServer = new AnonymousPipeServerStream( PipeDirection.Out ) ) {
    var pipeServerTask = Task.Run(
        async () => {
            using( var stream = getInputStream() ) {
                await stream.CopyToAsync( new TransformingOutputStream( pipeServer ) );
            }
            pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
            pipeServer.Dispose();
        } );

    using( var client = new AnonymousPipeClientStream( PipeDirection.In, pipeServer.ClientSafePipeHandle ) ) {
        MagicStreamReadingLibrary.ProcessStream( client );
    }
    pipeServerTask.Wait();
}
```

Comment: Oh yea, that is a lot simpler than my idea. I would go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Write it to a flat file then read it back out.

Comment: You're technically not wrong! But let's see if we can do it in a way that allows it to be streamed. Who knows how long that stream is!

Comment: A few years later and less snarky, i had to do a similar thing in golang recently.  The solution that I used in that case, @SamRueby , was to do it in a buffer - chunks a couple hundred bytes long at once.  Luckily we didn't need to do much parsing as we went, which would've been painful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I just threw together, it should in theory work (untested, I just know it compiles correctly).

```
public class BufferingStream
{
    private readonly Stream _readingStream;
    private readonly Stream _writingStream;
    private BlockingCollection<byte[]> _buffer;

    public BufferingStream()
    {
        _buffer = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>(new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>());
        _readingStream = new InternalReadingStream(_buffer);
        _writingStream = new InternalWritingStream(_buffer);
    }

    public BufferingStream(int maxQueueLength)
    {
        _buffer = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>(new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>(), maxQueueLength);
        _readingStream = new InternalReadingStream(_buffer);
        _writingStream = new InternalWritingStream(_buffer);
    }
    public Stream GetReadingStream()
    {
        return _readingStream;
    }

    public Stream GetWritingStream()
    {
        return _writingStream;
    }

    public int QueueLength
    {
        get { return _buffer.Count; }
    }

    public class InternalWritingStream : Stream
    {
        private readonly BlockingCollection<byte[]> _queuedBytes;

        public InternalWritingStream(BlockingCollection<byte[]> queuedBytes)
        {
            _queuedBytes = queuedBytes;
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            byte[] internalBuffer = new byte[count];
            Array.Copy(buffer, offset, internalBuffer, 0, count);
            _queuedBytes.Add(internalBuffer);
        }

        public override void Close()
        {
            _queuedBytes.CompleteAdding();
            base.Close();
        }

        public override void Flush()
        {
        }

        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override void SetLength(long value)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override bool CanSeek
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public override long Length
        {
            get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        }

        public override long Position
        {
            get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
            set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        }
    }

    private sealed class InternalReadingStream : Stream
    {
        private readonly BlockingCollection<byte[]> _queuedBytes;
        private byte[] _currentItem;
        private int _currentItemOffset;

        public InternalReadingStream(BlockingCollection<byte[]> queuedBytes)
        {
            _queuedBytes = queuedBytes;
            _currentItem = new byte[0];
            _currentItemOffset = 0;
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            if (_currentItemOffset == _currentItem.Length)
            {
                //Try to take the next buffer, if we can't take a item it means we where done adding from the source.
                var taken = _queuedBytes.TryTake(out _currentItem, Timeout.Infinite);
                if (!taken)
                    return 0;

                _currentItemOffset = 0;
            }
            var bytesToRead = Math.Min(count, _currentItem.Length - _currentItemOffset);
            Array.Copy(_currentItem, _currentItemOffset, buffer, offset, bytesToRead);
            _currentItemOffset += bytesToRead;

            return bytesToRead;
        }

        public override void Flush()
        {
        }

        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override void SetLength(long value)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override bool CanRead
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public override bool CanSeek
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override long Length
        {
            get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        }

        public override long Position
        {
            get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
            set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        }
    }
}
```

The way it would work in your use case would be

```
var bufferingStream = new BufferingStream();

Task.Run(() =>
{
    using(var inputStream = GetTheStreamFromSomewhere();
    using(var finalDestinationOutputStream = bufferingStream.GetWritingStream())
    using(var outputStream = new TransformingOutputStream(finalDestinationOutputStream))
    {
        inputStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
    }
}

using(var someInputStream = bufferingStream.GetReadingStream()) //Technically a using is not necessary on the reading stream but it is good to keep good habits.
{
    MagicStreamReadingLibrary.ProcessStream(someInputStream);
}
```

Initially calls to `.Read(` calls `ProcessStream` makes will block until data becomes available. As bytes become available `.Read(` unblocks and passes along the data. Once `finalDestinationOutputStream` is disposed it will mark the queue as completed adding and once `outputStream` finishes its last read it will just return 0 for any subsequent calls.

If you find that your writer is much faster than your reader you may want to pass in a max queue length so writes will block till the reader has a chance to read.